# Can't form correct JSON response for the client

Tags: java, javascript, json, get

I send a `GET` request int this way:

```
$.ajax({
    url: myUrl,
    type:"GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: callback        
});
```

On the server side, I form the following `json` string and send it to the client:

```
"{'composers':
    {'composer':
        {
        'id':2,
        'firstName': 'Arcangelo',
        'lastName': 'Corelli'
        }
    },
    {'composer':
        {
        'id':7,
        'firstName': 'Antonio',
        'lastName': 'Vivaldi'
        }
    }
}"
```

Client side just get nothing! **But If I use XML format for the response it works fine!** I'm setting content type like this:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
```

Comment: When in doubt , http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON needs to make the `composers` property an array:

```
{
    "composers": [
        {
            "composer": {
                "id": 2,
                "firstName": "Arcangelo",
                "lastName": "Corelli"
            }
        },
        {
            "composer": {
                "id": 7,
                "firstName": "Antonio",
                "lastName": "Vivaldi"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I would also recommend a slimmer version which removes the composer property, since it is pretty intuitive that a property `composers` assigned an array contains composer objects.

```
{
    "composers": [
        {
                "id": 2,
                "firstName": "Arcangelo",
                "lastName": "Corelli"
        },
        {
                "id": 7,
                "firstName": "Antonio",
                "lastName": "Vivaldi"
        }
    ]
}
```

Also JSON uses double quote instead of single quotes, you will need to replace as appropriate.

When you encounter these types of issues in the future just take your JSON over to [json lint](http://pro.jsonlint.com/) to validate, it will tell you all of the problems.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your JSON is malformed.

The `composers` element looks like to be an array and the JSON should be more like:

```
{"composers":
    [
        {
        "id":2,
        "firstName": "Arcangelo",
        "lastName": "Corelli"
        },
        {
         "id":7,
         "firstName': "Antonio",
         "lastName': "Vivaldi"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have JSON error . Fix it.

```
"{'composers':[
    {'composer':
        {
        'id':2,
        'firstName': 'Arcangelo',
        'lastName': 'Corelli'
        }
    },
    {'composer':
        {
        'id':7,
        'firstName': 'Antonio',
        'lastName': 'Vivaldi'
        }
    }
  ]
}"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
{
    "composers": [
        {
            "composer": {
                "id": 2,
                "firstName": "Arcangelo",
                "lastName": "Corelli"
            }
        },
        {
            "composer": {
                "id": 7,
                "firstName": "Antonio",
                "lastName": "Vivaldi"
            }
        }
    ]
}


and check your json is valid or not using jsonlint
```